# Meteor - Parse Data from Incoming HTTP Request

Tags: parsing, http, meteor, iron-router

For outgoing HTTP requests (using meteor.http.call) I can define params and/or data.  The results are then available (via results.content).

How do I access and parse the body/contents/data of incoming HTTP requests?

Using iron-router, I have got as far as this:

```
Router.map(function () {
this.route('httpTest', {
path: '/httpTest',
action: function () {
  var request = this.request;
  var response = this.response;      
  console.log('request_body: '+ request.body);
  // request.body does not work.  what should it be????
```

N.B. I understand that I CAN access query parameters, but I want to access form data and/or json data from the body of an incoming http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be working because of the missing `where: 'server'`. Here is a working example:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('test', {
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {
      console.log(this.request.body.make);
      console.log(this.request.body.model);
      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      this.response.end('hello!\n');
    }
  });
});
```

From the command line I can hit this route with:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"make":"honda","model":"civic"}' http://localhost:3000/test
```

Which prints the expected `honda` and `civic` in the server's terminal. It looks like `this.request.body` is already parsed so you can access any variables directly which is nice if your input is json.

Comment: `this.request.body.make` does not work any more, this does `this.request.make`

Answer (score 2):

The request is an [incoming http message](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), which is a [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream), so you can get the data of the request by reading from that stream.

The following should work (but I haven't tested it):

```
var readable = this.request;
var alldata = "";
readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  alldata += chunk;
})
readable.on('end', function() {
  console.log('do something with alldata');
});
```

Comment: This is helpful and has pointed me to the node documentation.  However the code above returns "Cannot call method 'on' of undefined route.action" Any clues?  Thanks

Comment: as David was pointing out, you are missing the "where;'server'", so you are executing this on the client it seems, where this.request is indeed undefined, as it the error is telling you here.

Comment: yes that fixes both methods - I have accepted David's answer because I am indeed receiving json and this approach is simple and intuitive.  Many thanks

Comment: In my case, the "end" event doesn't get fired: maybe because the stream gets consumed before issuing the readable.on("end")?

Answer (score 1):

To read the raw body, without having Node.js JSON-ify it, in a synchronous way, I used this:

```
Router.route("my/api", function() {
    var rawBody = "";
    var chunk;
    while ((chunk = this.request.read()) !== null) {
        rawBody += chunk;
    }
}, { where: "server" });
```

(the asynch way proposed in another answer here didn't worked for me, although it should as per Node.js documentation).